# OutputStreamWriter IOException occurs

Tags: java, android, java-io

Currently I have this code where I copy paste from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610171/saving-a-text-file-to-public-internal-memory-location-in-android) into my source code. But due to some reason unknown to me, the `OutputStreamWriter` keep giving `IOException`. And I'm clueless on what cause this and how to fix it. Please help. Below is my code.

```
 public void generateNoteOnSD(){// create a File object for the parent directory
    try {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File myFile = new File(path, "mytextfile.txt");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append("the text I want added to the file");

        Log.d("Save File  Test : ","Success");

        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //do something if an IOException occurs.
        Log.d("Save File Test : ","Failed");
    }
}
```

I have already included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in the manifest, and also running the code in `AsyncTask - onPostExecute` and on AVD with Lollipop version.

My stacktrace:

```
08-28 11:22:52.788 30478-30478/com.example.azrie.dummyvoice E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG: I got an error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/mytextfile.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
at com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.ReadHTML.generateNoteOnSD(ReadHTML.java:126)
at com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.ReadHTML.onPostExecute(ReadHTML.java:78)
at com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.ReadHTML.onPostExecute(ReadHTML.java:37)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87) 
at com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.ReadHTML.generateNoteOnSD(ReadHTML.java:126) 
at com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.ReadHTML.onPostExecute(ReadHTML.java:78) 
at com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.ReadHTML.onPostExecute(ReadHTML.java:37) 
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651) 
at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Maybe if you provide the stacktrace of your IOException, we can help

Comment: Hello. I added my stacktrace. Thank you.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android

Comment: `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`. It's right there in the stack trace. You don't have permission to open that file. Possibly the filename is really a directory for example.

Comment: @EJP Yes. I didn't know that in android 23+ you need to request for permission even though you already declared them in the manifest. Thanks to Nicolas for the link.

Answer (score -1):

```
private static final String FILE_NAME="score.txt";
BufferedOutputStream o;
                try {
                    o = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(),FILE_NAME)));
                    String s = //here write what you want to write to the file . its got to be string to work
                    o.write(s.getBytes());
                    o.close();
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e ){

                }catch (IOException e){

                }
```

for me its work for every time and its not opening new file every time.
if you want to see it in action serch FightWithMath in the play store. you will need to fully restart the app after first login and its writing in the main screen and while the game running every time you win